# Drawing a String on C# webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drawstring

I want to know how do I create an Engraving function like on this website?

http://www.bluenile.com/product_engraving?engrave_action=add_to_existing_item&is_ring=1&lineID=47017522&oid=20375&ring_size=7

I have already googled about it, it seems like using Graphics.DrawString Method..

But all the tutorial is in windows form C# (not on webpage)..

Any idea how do I start?

Thank you..

Comment: You need to respond to an HTTP request with an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Use the System.Drawing namespace to create a bitmap to draw onto with `Graphics` object and then save the image to file or stream it to the browser for display. Check out [Creating Images on the Fly with ASP.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/2569/creating-images-on-the-fly-with-aspnet/) for a tutorial.
2. Use SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics). Check out [SVG Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/index.html).
3. Use HTML5 Canvas. Check out [Getting Started with the HTML 5 Canvas](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/05/06/getting-started-with-the-html-5-canvas.aspx) for a tutorial.

Comment: thanks Karl.. I prefer to use SVG.. Its better in pixels.. ;)